# ant overwriting my manifest.mf file

Tags: java, ant, manifest

I have an ant build that builds a jar and eventually packages it up into an ear. I'm retrieving a MANIFEST.MF file from one of my projects using the `<copy todir....>` command, however when ant creates the jar file its giving me a different MANIFEST.MF file, is there a way to stop this from happening?

***EDIT***
heres the error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\aahmad\Desktop\qa_build_xml_UPTODATE\Ant_Build_Script\build.xml:200: Unable to read manifest file: C:\Users\aahmad\Desktop\qa_build_xml_UPTODATE\Ant_Build_Script\legacy\build\META-INF (C:\Users\aahmad\Desktop\qa_build_xml_UPTODATE\Ant_Build_Script\legacy\build\META-INF (Access is denied))
```

***EDIT***
is this correct?

```
    <jar jarfile="${myjardirectory}/lib/myjar.jar" basedir="${mybuildpath}" manifest="${mymetainf}" />
```

Comment: If you just want to compress your files maybe use `Zip` task?

Comment: no I need the jar file- or maybe you're right.. hmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [`jar`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) task allows you to point to the manifest file using the `manifest` attribute.

> the manifest file to use. This can be either the location of a manifest, or the name of a jar added through a fileset. If its the name of an added jar, the task expects the manifest to be in the jar at META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Note that even if you specify the manifest file with this attribute, you can still add attributes to this manifest using the nested `manifest` element. In this case, the two manifests will be "merged".

Comment: im getting "access is denied" when it tries to open the META-INF folder with the manifest file in it

Comment: Can you update your post with the updated code and the exact error?

Comment: updated, cant put anything more, its for work and they dont let us post any code snippets

Comment: Well... Seems you don't have access to this path. Try moving the manifest (and if possible all your build workspace) to another path where you have access privileges.

Comment: can you see my updated question, i have another question

Comment: Seems fine. Just check if it works and if you're not sure always consult the task documentation.